# What's the difference between tsql and isql?

Tags: sql-server

I saw this in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588902/sql-server-trouble-with-rails),and is really confused

Comment: wamp correct me if I'm wrong but I think you are asking about the tsql command and its difference to the isql command in the post you linked to right?

Answer (score 0):

TSql is Microsoft's native Transaction Sql language for SQL Server.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189826(SQL.90).aspx

iSql appears to be an old Microsoft utility that allows you to run SQL statements against SQL Server.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214007(SQL.80).aspx

Comment: actually no - today isql is osql. Command line utilities are still usefull for example to execute SQL from scripts ;)

Answer (score 0):

isql is an old CLI tool that I believe Microsoft has deprecated.  It looks like from this [webpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tsql) that tsql is a Linux CLI tool for querying databases and doing diagnostics.

Answer (score -1):

SQL Server applications must be using T-SQL statements to communicate with the server, but how your T-SQL is written and run can ultimately impact your server performance.

isql defines the order of the date format as month, date, and year (mm dd yyyy hh:mmAM (or PM)) regardless of the locale environment. To change this default order, use the convert function.
isql [-b] [-e] [-F] [-p] [-n] [-v] [-X] [-Y] [-Q]

Comment: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.utility/html/utility/utility210.htm http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tutorial/T-SQL-Learning-Guide